# Video file validation in django

Tags: django, validation

First we upload the video file and try to convert in .flv video file if convert the video  file in .flv file then no problem and if not able to convert in .flv file then show messages like this video format is not supported..bcz some video file not converted in .flv like(swf)

Comment: Yeah, the header of the question is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate with the [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) library, as it extracts metadata from audio/video/image files, and it can report you the file type.

According to the docs you can even check other informations such as type of codec:
http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/Flash.html